# Should I switch from "urllib.request.urlretrieve(..)" to "urllib.request.urlopen(..)"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, urlopen, urlretrieve

#### 1. Deprecation problem

In **Python 3.7**, I download a big file from a `URL` using the `urllib.request.urlretrieve(..)` function. In the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) I read the following just above the `urllib.request.urlretrieve(..)` docs:

> **Legacy interface**
>   The following functions and classes are ported from the Python 2 module urllib (as opposed to urllib2). They might become deprecated at some point in the future.

#### 2. Searching an alternative

To keep my code future-proof, I'm on the lookout for an alternative. The official Python docs don't mention a specific one, but it looks like `urllib.request.urlopen(..)` is the most straightforward candidate. It's at the top of the docs page.

Unfortunately, the alternatives - like `urlopen(..)` - *don't provide the `reporthook` argument.* This argument is a callable you pass to the `urlretrieve(..)` function. In turn, `urlretrieve(..)` calls it regularly with the following arguments:

- block nr.
- block size
- total file size

I use it to update a progressbar. That's why I miss the `reporthook` argument in alternatives.

#### 3. urlretrieve(..) vs urlopen(..)

I discovered that *`urlretrieve(..)` simply uses `urlopen(..)`*. See the `request.py` code file in the Python 3.7 installation (Python37/Lib/urllib/request.py):

```py
_url_tempfiles = []
def urlretrieve(url, filename=None, reporthook=None, data=None):
    """
    Retrieve a URL into a temporary location on disk.

    Requires a URL argument. If a filename is passed, it is used as
    the temporary file location. The reporthook argument should be
    a callable that accepts a block number, a read size, and the
    total file size of the URL target. The data argument should be
    valid URL encoded data.

    If a filename is passed and the URL points to a local resource,
    the result is a copy from local file to new file.

    Returns a tuple containing the path to the newly created
    data file as well as the resulting HTTPMessage object.
    """
    url_type, path = splittype(url)

    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
        headers = fp.info()

        # Just return the local path and the "headers" for file://
        # URLs. No sense in performing a copy unless requested.
        if url_type == "file" and not filename:
            return os.path.normpath(path), headers

        # Handle temporary file setup.
        if filename:
            tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
        else:
            tfp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
            filename = tfp.name
            _url_tempfiles.append(filename)

        with tfp:
            result = filename, headers
            bs = 1024*8
            size = -1
            read = 0
            blocknum = 0
            if "content-length" in headers:
                size = int(headers["Content-Length"])

            if reporthook:
                reporthook(blocknum, bs, size)

            while True:
                block = fp.read(bs)
                if not block:
                    break
                read += len(block)
                tfp.write(block)
                blocknum += 1
                if reporthook:
                    reporthook(blocknum, bs, size)

    if size >= 0 and read < size:
        raise ContentTooShortError(
            "retrieval incomplete: got only %i out of %i bytes"
            % (read, size), result)

    return result
```

#### 4. Conclusion

From all this, I see three possible decisions:

1. I keep my code **unchanged**. Let's hope the `urlretrieve(..)` function won't get deprecated anytime soon.
2. I write myself a **replacement function** behaving like `urlretrieve(..)` on the outside and using `urlopen(..)` on the inside. Actually, such function would be a copy-paste of the code above. It feels unclean to do that - compared to using the official `urlretrieve(..)`.
3. I write myself a **replacement function** behaving like `urlretrieve(..)` on the outside and using something entirely different on the inside. But hey, why would I do that? `urlopen(..)` is not deprecated, so why not use it?

What decision would you take?

Comment: if you so afraid then copy `urlretrieve()` to your code and use it at once or only when there is no original `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`

Comment: See answers to similar questions: [alternative-of-urllib-urlretrieve-in-python-3-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358521/alternative-of-urllib-urlretrieve-in-python-3-5)  and [how-to-download-a-file-over-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-to-download-a-file-over-http/48691447#48691447)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example uses `urllib.request.urlopen` to download a zip file containing Oceania's crop production data from the FAO statistical database. In that example, it is necessary to define a minimal header, otherwise FAOSTAT throws an `Error 403: Forbidden`.

```
import shutil
import urllib.request
import tempfile

# Create a request object with URL and headers    
url = “http://fenixservices.fao.org/faostat/static/bulkdownloads/Production_Crops_Livestock_E_Oceania.zip”
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '}
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=header)

# Define the destination file
dest_file = tempfile.gettempdir() + '/' + 'crop.zip'
print(f“File located at:{dest_file}”)

# Create an http response object
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    # Create a file object
    with open(dest_file, "wb") as f:
        # Copy the binary content of the response to the file
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, f)
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691447/2641825 for the request part and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66591873/2641825 for the header part, see also urllib's documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html

Comment: Thanks! This is great :-)