# Save an image with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.7

this is source i want download :

```
<div id="image-captcha-section" class="a-section a-spacing-large">
  <input type="hidden" name="use_image_captcha" value="true" id="use_image_captcha">
  <div class="a-section a-spacing-base">
    <h4>
      Enter the characters you see
    </h4>

<div id="auth-captcha-image-container" class="a-section a-text-center">
  <img alt="Visual CAPTCHA image, continue down for an audio option." src="https://opfcaptcha-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/b2ebf54f0e9e48ca8e4e8552974565c1.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA5WBBRBBB3EQNKAH5&amp;Expires=1568911776&amp;Signature=BQzylyeOezMXtuLXgnfY3IX0CdA%3D" data-refresh-url="/ap/captcha?appAction=REGISTER&amp;captchaObfuscationLevel=ape%3AZWFzeQ%3D%3D&amp;captchaType=image&amp;marketPlaceId=A1EVAM02EL8SFB" id="auth-captcha-image">
</div>
```

and this is my code :

```
                    img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="auth-captcha-image"]')
                    src = img.get_attribute('src')
                    # download the image
                    urllib.urlretrieve(src, "captcha.jpg")
                    print("Done")
```

i have searched on other topic but can't save this image have URL : https://opfcaptcha-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/b2ebf54f0e9e48ca8e4e8552974565c1.jpg

thanks for help me!

Comment: _"but can't save this image"_ - why can't you? What happens when you try?

Comment: Which version of python are you using. It is disabled in python 3.4 and above.

Comment: Hi, i'm using Python 3.7.4 . so how i can fix ? downgrade the python ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
[Alternative of urllib.urlretrieve in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358521/alternative-of-urllib-urlretrieve-in-python-3-5)
If you are using python 3.5 and above may be this is the right approach

Comment: i'm using Python 3.7.4

Comment: so did the link help?

Answer (score 1):

Tag name you have selected is `div` but it is an `img` tag.So change your xpath to locate the element.

```
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@id="auth-captcha-image"]')
src = img.get_attribute('src')
```